# Change page background when hovering over a link

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, sass

I want to have two different links and when hovering over one it changes the entire *PAGE* background to a different background-image-url. Then when I hover over the second link it changes the background-image-url to another picture. Is this possible? I am using Angular, I was thinking at first I could do this in css but I now think something more will be required. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create 2 css classes for different `background-image` and apply the class you need to parent on hover using Javascript. Not sure if this can be achieved using css only.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be possible with pure CSS because [selectors are unable to ascend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS#Limitations).

What you're trying to achieve can be easily done though. Just attach hover events to the links and in the event handlers, add a certain CSS class to the page. And then define the styles for that class of course.

To add the class, what you need to do is set a state value to a certain value and in the page element, add `*ngClass="{bgLink1: hovered === 'link1'}"` or something like that. You get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com" id="link1"></a>
    <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions" id="link2"></a>
</body>
<style>
body {
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#link1 {
    margin: 5vw;
}

#link2 {
    margin: 5vw;
}

#link1:hover body {
    background: url('');/*any url you want for the picture*/
}

#link2:hover body {
    background: url('');/*another url you want for the other picture*/
}
</style>
</html>
```

I really hope I could help you, if not it wouldn't hurt to write the question another time but with code or something so I can understand what you want

Comment: Where in the HTML is there a `body` element that is a descendant of an element with an ID of `link1` or `link2`?